# How to fill blank space when hide an item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerview in my activity and in each item i have two button and a ordernumber when minus bottom make zero the ordernumber, i want to hide this item and other item come up and fill the blank space.I hide the item with setVisibility() but i don`t know how to handle blank space.

this is my recyclerview adapter:

```
package com.test.mohammaddvi.snappfood.Adapter;
public class RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter.SingleItemBuyBasket> {

private ArrayList<FinalFood> foodList;
private Context mContext;
private View view;

public RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter(ArrayList<FinalFood> foodList, Context mContext) {
    this.foodList = foodList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter.SingleItemBuyBasket onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buybasketitem, null);
    return new RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter.SingleItemBuyBasket(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter.SingleItemBuyBasket holder, int position) {

    FinalFood food = foodList.get(position);
    holder.foodName.setText(food.getName());
    holder.foodDetails.setText(food.getDetails());
    holder.foodPrice.setText(food.getPrice());
    holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(food.getOrdernumber() + "");
    handleClick(holder, view);
}

private void handleClick(final RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter.SingleItemBuyBasket holder, final View view) {
    holder.foodPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FinalFood food = foodList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            int orderNumber = food.getOrdernumber();
            int newOrderNumber = orderNumber + 1;
            food.setOrdernumber(newOrderNumber);
            holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(newOrderNumber + "");
        }
    });
    holder.foodMinusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FinalFood food = foodList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            int orderNumber = food.getOrdernumber();
            if (orderNumber == 1) {
                int newOrderNumber = orderNumber - 1;
                food.setOrdernumber(newOrderNumber);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                int newOrderNumber = orderNumber - 1;
                food.setOrdernumber(newOrderNumber);
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(newOrderNumber + "");
            }

        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != foodList ? foodList.size() : 0);
}


public class SingleItemBuyBasket extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView foodName;
    TextView foodPrice;
    Button foodPlusButton;
    Button foodMinusButton;
    TextView foodOrderNumber;
    TextView foodDetails;

    SingleItemBuyBasket(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        this.foodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodNameInBuyBasket);
        this.foodPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodPriceInBuyBasket);
        this.foodDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodDetailsInBuyBasket);
        this.foodPlusButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plusbuttonInBuyBasket);
        this.foodMinusButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.minusbuttonInBuyBasket);
        this.foodOrderNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ordernumberInBuyBasket);
    }
}
}
```

and this is my activity:

```
package com.test.mohammaddvi.snappfood;
public class BuyBasket extends AppCompatActivity{
ArrayList<FinalFood> foods = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter recyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_basket);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    foods= (ArrayList<FinalFood>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("final");
    recyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter = new RecyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter(foods, BuyBasket.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(BuyBasket.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewBuyBasketAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: I think the you could remove the item/row as normal. In this way an appropriate animation is made for the delete action and the white space doesn't occurs.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better you delete the entire row rather than changing visibility. This is the code to remove the row. You need to call removeItem(position); method in your button onclickListener

```
  public void removeItem(int position)
  {
    // Remove specified position
    models.remove(position);
    // Notify adapter to remove the position
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    // Notify adapter about data changed
    notifyItemChanged(position);
    // Notify adapter about item range changed
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, arraylist.size());
  }
```

Comment: Why notify 3 times ? Only `notifyItemRemoved` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your xml, define two parents. One for the hidden content and the other for the item that you want to appear when you hide the first one

Try playing with View when clicking in one parent or the other:

```
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE) or view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```